# Convert a rating scale

Tags: algorithm, math, scale, rating

I have a website where people can evaluate some subjects. Here is the scale **[1-4]**.

[image]

However I probably have a problem in terms of readability of the overall rating. The most common scale is [1-5] in web.

Currently I am using for example `1.5 / 4`.

Google says:

*Ratings that don't use a 5-point scale: By default, Google assumes that your site uses a 5-point scale, where 5 is the best possible rating and 1 is the worst, but you can use any other scale. If you do, you can mark up the best and worst ratings, and Google will scale that to the 5-star system used in rich snippets.*

How can I do this type of conversion from a scale of 4 to 5?

Comment: How does Google scale?  Does it round to the nearest whole number, or does it maintain at least one decimal of precision?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have no idea. That information is not available in docs. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews

Comment: This might be a UX issue more than simply a mathematical one. Sometimes people use 4 point scales instead of 5 point scales because they want to exclude the possibility of "sitting on the fence" by giving a rating exactly in the middle of the range. You could preserve that property and keep the numbers whole by mapping 1->1, 2->2, 3->4, 4->5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do the scaling on your end, the obvious linear transformation is

```
oneToFive = (oneToFour - 1.0) * (4.0/3.0) + 1.0
```

Sanity check:

```
(1 - 1.0) * (4.0/3.0) + 1.0 == 1.0
(4 - 1.0) * (4.0/3.0) + 1.0 == 5.0
```

If you want have Google do it, just keep reading on [the instructions page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews). You just need to set a couple of values:

> `reviewRating.bestRating` `Text*`
>   The highest value allowed in this rating system.
>   * Required if the rating system is not on a 5-point scale. If bestRating > is omitted, 5 is assumed.
>
> `reviewRating.worstRating` `Text*`
>   The lowest value allowed in this rating system.
>   * Required if the rating system is not on a 5-point scale. If worstRating > is omitted, 1 is assumed.

Comment: More formulaic:
`new_rating = ((rating - rating_worst) * (target_best - target_worst)/(rating_best - rating_worst)) + target_worst`